# Converting Mapserver default URL to a more user friendly version

Tags: openstreetmap, mapserver, osgeo

I use the default MapServer URL to view the map in browser.

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps/osm-google.map&mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all
```

How can I convert it to more general style such as http://foo.com ?

I just need to show my map in a specific URL like in maps.google.com or www.openstreetmap.com and nothing more. For example I want to hide my directories showing such as /home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps/ in the original URL. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a wrapper script to achieve this

```
#!/bin/sh
MAPSERV="/path/to/my/mapserv"
MAPFILE="/path/to/my/mapfile.map"
if [ "${REQUEST_METHOD}" = "GET" ]; then
  if [ -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ]; then
    QUERY_STRING="map=${MAPFILE}"
  else
    QUERY_STRING="map=${MAPFILE}&${QUERY_STRING}"
  fi
  exec ${MAPSERV}
else
  echo "Sorry, I only understand GET requests."
fi
exit 1
# End of Script
```

Source: [mapserver.org](http://mapserver.org/cgi/wrapper.html)

**PS: the script only works for GET requests.**

Another alternative is to use php/python mapscript for creating the web pages.
its very easy and you need to install corresponding mapscript bindings
see [here](http://mapserver.org/mapscript/index.html) for more info. Here is an [example](http://mapserver.org/mapscript/php/by_example.html) of php mapscript

Comment: Thank you @rashad for quick reply. I tried the example (the php one). I am stuck from the beginning. When I execute my .php file in browser nothing appears as told in the first output of the example. I used the example .php code given and used the mapfile I had. I changed the $map_path to my basemaps folder which included the osm-google.map file.

Comment: what does the error log says. if you are using ubuntu it should be located in /var/log/apache2/error.log. else please find the location of apache error log and access log

Answer (score 0):

There are alternatives to wrapper scripts. See: http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#changing-the-online-resource-url